# sssd.service failed in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

I installed the stable version of Ubuntu 20.10 as soon as it released, but there is this error I'm getting after installing it. Should it bother?

[image: sssd.service failed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What SSSD is (source: `apt show sssd-common`):

> Description: System Security Services Daemon -- common files
> Provides a set of daemons to manage access to remote directories and
> authentication mechanisms. It provides an NSS and PAM interface toward
> the system and a pluggable backend system to connect to multiple different
> account sources. It is also the basis to provide client auditing and policy
> services for projects like FreeIPA.

SSSD is not part of a stock Ubuntu Desktop install.

If you don't use a remote authentication server, then you likely don't need the SSSD packages at all.

If you do use a remote authentication server, then this failure may be important. Contact your network admin.

Comment: So is it safe to remove all the sssd packages?

Comment: Depends upon why you originally installed those packages. If you don't know why they were installed, and you don't use a remote authentication server, then go ahead and try uninstalling them. This random person on the internet says that it should be safe enough.

Comment: The packages were installed with 20.10 upgrade. I did not ask for it. So i'll remove all of them. I have had the same issue on the 2 upgrades that I have done.